# IBM Voice Agent RTP port range

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-voice-gateway

What range of RTP/SRTP ports does IBM Voice Agent use for inbound SIP / SIP+TLS?

[Voice Gateway port documentation](http://%20https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS4U29/ports.html) provides the default RTP port range (16384-16394) but I figure Voice Agent may have a wider/different range.

Why? The range is needed to configure our SBC for bridging calls to IBM Cloud.

Answer (score 0):

The RTP port range used by IBM Voice Agent is 1024-65148.